# How to create open square/checkbox style list marker for HTML unordered list?

Tags: html, css

I need to make a bulleted list on a web page with markers (bullets) that look like empty checkboxes (basically, the outline of a square). I know that you can specify the list marker via the list-style-type property in CSS, but the options available (filled circle, open circle, filled square, etc.) are not what I need.

I don't need these to actually function like checkboxes. I just want them to be squares, not filled in.

Comment: Why don't you just make an image and use it for the bullets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/WLQqf/

```
li 
{ 
    list-style-image: url('http://bit.ly/qunMkL'); 
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Comment: just making it more readable. It's a gif on some crappy site, I'm sure they won't care

Comment: Thanks; this is what I was looking for. As I noted, I didn't want it to behave like a checkbox, so I don't want any hover/click functionality.

Answer (score 24):

You can [use images instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/list-style-image)... unless you need it to *function* like a checkbox

Well here's a fun little demo :P

http://jsfiddle.net/nN8k7/

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

```
li:before
{
    content: "\2610";
    margin-right:5px;
}

li:hover:before
{
    content: "\2611";
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

Or...

http://jsfiddle.net/nN8k7/1/

I am just having too much fun with this. :P

Comment: What's the 2610 and 2611. Please explain.

Comment: @Jawad it's the unicode characters for ☐ and ☑. :P Kinda corny but fun to make.  It only works in modern browsers though (because of :before).

Answer (score 2):

If you need them to be *transparent*, empty squares that cannot be checked:

```
<style type="text/css">
input[type='checkbox'] {
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background:transparent;
    border:1px solid black;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked {
    background: transparent; /* stay transparent, even after checked */
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another possibility. I've had good luck using the List Style None and using HTML code for the empty boxes as well as checkmarks and other wingdings etc.

```
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
  <li>&#9633; The first thing
  <li>&#9633; Another thing  </ul>
```

preview below

□ The first thing

□ Another thing

Here's a link to HTML code for lots of symbols.
http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/index.php?w=dingb

FileFormat.info is another good site

Comment: Needless to say the CSS on this site is causing an extra bullet of the ordinary regulation variety.

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me. You can specify the square in `list-style-type` of `ul` like below:

```css
    ul.square-box  {
       list-style-type: "\2610   ";
    }
```

```html
    <ul class="square-box">
       <li>Lion</li>
       <li>Tiger</li>
       <li>Zebra</li>
    <ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use font-awesome. It's easier. http://fontawesome.io/icons/ type square and then use that with your list item.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a checkbox list with pure CSS and HTML, no images or frameworks.  I recommend to use [ballot boxes](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_symbols.asp) or [squares](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_geometric.asp) as the checkbox symbol.  This is useful for printable checklists, since the checkboxes are non-functional.  Note that you must use hexadecimal entities in the CSS 'content', since named and decimal entities will not work.

```css
ul { list-style-type: none; }
li::before { content: "\2610"; margin-right: 0.5em; }
```

```html
<ul>
<li>use hexadecimal entities in content</li>
<li>use the ballot box symbol</li>
<li>and apply a right-margin</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

This thread was dead a very long time ago, but I thought I'd answer it just in case you were like me and tried to google it more recently, but couldn't find the answer. I finally found it so here you are:

```
<ul style="list-style-type:myanmar;">
  <li>la</li>
  <li>la</li>
  <li>la</li>
  <li>la</li>
  <li>la</li>
  <li>la</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't make empty squares next to the <li> elements as the question asks.  This makes Burmese numbering.  This is cool though and I didn't know this was possible- for a complete list of vanilla CSS marker options, see this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type .  It looks like there is no option for a "hollow square", so the best bet is to try one of the options above.